# не видно GWT-контролов на web-странице

Tags: java, gwt, maven

Есть простейшее gwt-приложение. Немного текста и кнопка.
На этапе отладки, всё работает хорошо. Стоит мне упаковать проект в war, и задеплоить в TomCat, как переход по ссылке в web-браузере отображает только текст на html-странице, кнопки (почему-то) нет.
Сильно подозреваю, что это текст той самой html-страницы. До **EntryPoint** дело вообще не доходит.

На сколько я знаю, при компиляции GWT преобразует java в JavaScript. Может быть в этом дело? Как раз в JavaScript компиляции и нет при упаковке в war ?

Вот структура моего проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой **gwt2war.gwt.xml**:

```
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
<entry-point class='ru.javastudy.gwt2war.client.gwt2war'/>

<!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->

<servlet path='/gwt2warService' class='ru.javastudy.gwt2war.server.gwt2warServiceImpl'/>
```

Comment: Вы в War экспортируете после того как сделали компиляцию в скрипт? Пробовали устанавливать стандартную тему для компонентов?

Comment: Да, компилирую, потом в -  war. У меня там нет никаких тем, всё стандартное.

Comment: >>там нет никаких тем<< файл gwt2war.gwt.xml в нём конфигурации, в них ссылка на класс темы компонентов. По нему же, на этапе компиляции, перерабатываются все ресурсы преобразуются в строки (либо base64 либо чистый текст), после чего происходит инъекция этих ресурсов в html.

вообще, странная ситуация... я подобного "исчезания" не встречал. А в томкате у вас две копии библиотеки GWT лежат? (для отладки для релиза)

Comment: Ну как: я пакую в war при помощи IntellijIDEA, потом захожу в консоль TomCat-а и делаю Deploy War. Там можно загрузить War-ник из указанного каталога и нажать Deploy. так и делаю.

Comment: Наверно не правильно выразился, повторюсь - в JBOSS-е, TomCat-е и других серверах есть папка с библиотеками. Там должна лежать копия (или две) вашего GWT jar-ника. Так вот, насколько помню, для той же EXT, было две версии, для отладки и для работы. Вы отладку вообще делали через Google-плагины, или там же, в томкате и отлаживали?

Comment: Ну отладку я делал в среде IntellijIDEA. Через google-плагины. И там всё работает. В томкате я только деплою war-ник. А под "GWT jar-ником" Вы понимаете .jar - файл (стороннюю библиотеку) необходимый для правильного функционирования всего проекта?

Comment: Заметил такую особенность: когда запускаю gwt-проект, то в адресе web-страницы это: http://127.0.0.1:8888/gwt2war.html Но если запустить  задеплоеный war в томкате, то ссылка совсем другая: http://localhost:8080/gwt2war-1.0/gwt2war.html т.е. порт даже другой. В этом может быть причина?

Comment: >> localhost:8080/gwt2war-1.0/gwt2war.html << если я не ошибаюсь, следуя вашей конфигурации, ссылка на сервлет совсем другая: "localhost:8080/gwt2war_demo/gwt2warService". Сами ссылки формируются следующим образом "хост:порт/Имя_проекта_с_учётом_регистра/Сервлет". То что ссылка меняется при дебаге и реальном запуске - это нормально.

Comment: О, спасибо. Я проверю!

Comment: То же смое (((( Не думал что такой "бубен" кроется при компановке GWT в war

Answer (score 1):

О, неужели! Заработало. Что я сделал: Я выбрал Run-конфигурацию для TomCat-а а не gwt-приложения. Запустил её. В рез-те чего у меня всё успешно запустилось, отработало и отобразилось. Но заметил, что war-архива у меня по прежнему нет. Я сделал build и сформировался war-ник. Но заметил, что помимо другиг папок в target-директории появилась папочка gwt2war-1.0 \ gwt2war с кучей html-ээлек, одним rpc-Файлом и одним .nocache.js Теперь этот "архивчик" весит 69 мегабайт и штатными средствами томката не деплоится (через консоль). Пришлось руками скопировать в webapps-папку, и там он сам развернулся. Спустя какое то время я зашел по ссылке: http://localhost:8080/gwt2war-1.0/gwt2war.html и заработало. Ужас ))))

Answer (score 0):

Странное дело. Опубликованный war-архив прекрасно работает на локальном хосте, где стоит tomcat. Но стоит его опубликовать на реальный удаленный сервер (с той же версией томката) и обратиться по адресу: [http://имя_сервера:8080/gwt2war-1.0/gwt2war.html](http://%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0:8080/gwt2war-1.0/gwt2war.html) - отображается ТОЛЬКО html-страница без кнопки. Как будто что-то режет javascript контролы...
Подскажите - куда глянуть? ((

Comment: Видимо отвечу сам себе. Глянуть в сторону других браузеров. Т.к. в том же google chrom всё отображается.